# Where is "generic_start_main()" defined?

Tags: glibc, libc

I got a segmentation fault from running a program. The `backtrace` command in `gdb` shows that the calling stack is

```
#0  0x000000001048d594 in .__libc_csu_init ()
#1  0x000000001048ce20 in .generic_start_main ()
#2  0x000000001048d030 in .__libc_start_main ()
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Can someone tell me where `generic_start_main()` is defined? I tried to search in `glibc` with
`grep -R generic_start_main *` but only got

```
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/powerpc/libc-start.c:29:#define LIBC_START_MAIN generic_start_main
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/powerpc/libc-start.c:102:  return generic_start_main (stinfo->main, argc, argv, auxvec,
```

I'm running programs on a `3.10.0 Linux` on a 64-bit PowerPC machine.

Answer (score 1):

> but only got

You give up too easily. Look in `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/powerpc/libc-start.c`, and you'll see that it `#include <csu/libc-start.c>` after defining `LIBC_START_MAIN`, and the `csu/libc-start.c` [has](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c;h=494132368f8fe486f8e33841dc8d7e51ee2f94d9;hb=HEAD#l128):

```
STATIC int
LIBC_START_MAIN (int (*main) (int, char **, char ** MAIN_AUXVEC_DECL),
                  int argc, char **argv,
#ifdef LIBC_START_MAIN_AUXVEC_ARG
                  ElfW(auxv_t) *auxvec,
#endif
                  __typeof (main) init,
                  void (*fini) (void),
                  void (*rtld_fini) (void), void *stack_end)
 { ...
```

**Update:**

> I'm not very familiar with how the #define macro works.

The `#define` creates a *text substitution* rule for the preprocessor. For example:

```
#define FOO Bar
```

tells the preprocessor: every time you see `FOO`, replace it with `Bar` (there are some details I am sweeping under the rug here, but they are not important for this question).

So, given:

```
#define LIBC_START_MAIN generic_start_main
int LIBC_START_MAIN() { ... }
```

This is what the compiler sees after preprocessing:

```
int generic_start_main() { ... }
```

Comment: After `#define LIBC_START_MAIN generic_start_main`, are these two names aliases to each other? I found the definition for `LIBC_START_MAIN` in `csu/libc-start.c`, but I didn't realize that defining `LIBC_START_MAIN` is equivalent to defining `generic_start_main`.

Comment: @Jay You don't appear to understand how preprocessing works. Do you *really* not understand this, or did you just not think it through?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how the #define macro works. I only knew that in a `#define expr1 expr2` the first expression is an alias to the second and you need define expr2 somewhere. I didn't know you can also define expr1 somewhere and use expr2 directly. That's why even after I checked the `csu/libc-start.c` I still didn't know where `generic_start_main` is defined - I thought `generic_start_main` **must** be defined explicitly.
Now I know `expr1` and `expr2` are alias to each other one and can replace another wherever needed.

Comment: @Jay I've updated the answer, to hopefully clarify this for you. There are no *aliases* here.